# Core-Data complex countForFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Suppose i have a one to many relationship between two model entities `Entity One` and `Entity Many`, and `Entity One` has a `name` field,

> **Entity One** (1) --- (m) **Entity Many**

I want to check if an `Entity One` exist with `name` equal to `"one"` and has associated `Entity Many` records. Can i perform this check using `countForFetchRequest:` method? How? I'm not very good very predicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up doing this, and seems to be working:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityA" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@ AND relationshipRecords.@count != 0", aName];

NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger numberOfRecords = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

[fetchRequest release];
```